# Calculate number of divs on a row javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, count

I am trying to count the number of divs on a row using javascript.
Reason for it is because depending on browser size, the number can decrease or increase. The max number I have is 5 divs on a row but it can go down to 1 on mobile.

I need to know if the div I've clicked on belongs to a row of 5 or 4 or 3 or 2 or 1.
I have absolutely no clue where to start so I don't have a solution.

```
.div-inner {
display: inline-block;
}
<div class="div-inner">1</div>
<div class="div-inner">2</div>
<div class="div-inner">3</div>
<div class="div-inner">4</div>
<div class="div-inner">5</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("div-inner").length`

Comment: What you mean *row*?

Comment: Divs are next to each other, i've added display inline-block. When the browser changes to mobile width they start dropping as it is responsive. I need to know on the moment i click on a div if it is on a row with 5 or 2 or 1

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve with this? The way you’ve described the problem suggests that you are, or might be, using media breakpoints to inform your design so the current breakpoint could be used to let you know the current layout. If you take the time to show your [mcve] then we can reproduce, and better understand, your problem and then better answer the problem.

Comment: Sounds like this problem could be fixed using a grid-like system. Check the grid of Bootstrap for example and see how it works.

Comment: yes, this should be solved with CSS, not JS

Comment: I am having a dynamic template, where I have information from the div stored in a javascript obj. The moment you add to that object, a div is created so I don't have a fix number of divs but the max number of divs inside a row will always be 5. As David said, I am trying to kind of refer to breakpoints to know how many divs are on a row when going mobile, because i want when I click any of them to display another div with info about that div under the immediate row where the div is...  i have div div div on the same row then when i click on div 2 for example, the info will be under the 3 divs

Comment: This solution would do it: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/importing-css-breakpoints-into-javascript

Comment: You need to share enough of your code that we can reproduce, and understand, your problem.